# Casting to T raises unchecked lint

Tags: java, android, generics, intellij-idea

For the following snippet:

```
public class DriverRequestsColumnFragment<T extends BaseColumnPagerAdapter> {    
    private T adapter = (T) new RequestsColumnNowAdapter();   
}
```

where:

```
public class RequestsColumnNowAdapter extends BaseColumnPagerAdapter {

}
```

Android Studio (and probably Intellij IDEA) raises a "unchecked" lint.
I can always suppress it with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` but is it the correct way to deal with it?

### Update:

I want to have a `private BaseColumnPagerAdapter adapter;` which gets extended by two classes. (e.g. `A extends BaseColumnPagerAdapter` and `B extends BaseColumnPagerAdapter`).

In the constructor of the DriverRequestsColumnFragment I pass a boolean which creates a new `A` or `B` but this should be class available so something like:

```
public class DriverRequestsColumnFragment<T extends BaseColumnPagerAdapter> {
    private T adapter ;

    public DriverRequestsColumnFragment(boolean choose){
        if(choose)
            adapter = (T) new A();
        else
            adapter = (T) new B();
    }

}
```

Comment: No, the warning is real and about a real problem. What do you really want to achieve with generics here?

Comment: @laalto thanks. See above updated example code

Comment: There's nothing forcing `T extends RequestColumnNowAdapter` which is why you are getting the unchecked cast warning. Just because `T extends BaseColumnPagerAdapter` and `RequestColumnNowAdapter extends BaseColumnPagerAdapter` it does not mean `T extends RequestColumnNowAdapter`

Comment: @steve Oh thanks steve. Nice explanation. I failed. I could just have `private BaseColumnPagerAdapter adapter;`

Comment: @Diolor exactly. You're welcome. If it solved your problem I will move my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved from comments:

There's nothing forcing `T extends RequestColumnNowAdapter` which is why you are getting the unchecked cast warning. Just because `T extends BaseColumnPagerAdapter` and `RequestColumnNowAdapter extends BaseColumnPagerAdapter` it does not mean that `T extends RequestColumnNowAdapter`